# Remove preset binding in fish shell

Tags: fish

I am unable to remove the default binding in Fish shell for `CTRL + p`.

I want to activate separate "background" app outside of the terminal using the `CTRL+P` shortcut.

I have tried:

```bash
bind --erase \cp up-or-search
```

However the binding remains. How can I remove the preset bindings? The [documentation](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/bind.html) does not mention it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want this shortcut to propagate up to the parent process rather than Fish swallowing it and reacting to it.

That's not how it works.

If by "parent process" you mean the terminal, that gets first dibs on every key. It gets to decide what is passed on and what isn't.

If by "parent process" you mean an in-terminal process that started fish: That typically stays in the background and doesn't read any keys at all.

And fish will (and has to) read all input it receives, even if it then decides to do nothing. Reading it is how it finds out what it has to do, and it cannot stuff the input back.

And the terminal has no idea what the processes running inside it have bound or not, so it also can't decide to send keys that it knows the shell will do something with and keep others for itself.

Your mental model is incorrect.

> How can I remove the preset bindings?

To erase a preset binding, you could run

```
bind --erase --preset \cp
```

However, you would have to arrange for that to be run after the binding has actually been set up. You might want to store it in a function called `fish_user_key_bindings`. Fish runs that after it sets up the bindings, whenever it does it (e.g. if you switch to vi-mode it'll rerun it).

Typically to disable a binding you would rather make your own that does nothing, like

```
bind \cp true
```

Not that this would help what you want to do, see above.

Comment: Thanks for the informational answer and on-going support to development of Fish @faho! I wished to activate separate "background" app using the `CTRL`+`P` i.e. Paletro but like you say it does not work after removing the binding. This is odd though because I can activate other app with similar shortcuts e.g. `Cmd`+`Space` for LaunchBar, `CTRL`+`B` for Bartender, `CTRL`+`K` for Fantastical, `CTRL`+`\`` for PopClip. Do you know what could be the difference?

Comment: The difference is that those bindings are bound outside of the terminal or directly in the terminal itself, and so they are read and consumed before they ever reach fish. Fish has nothing to do with it.

Comment: ctrl+b and ctrl+k are also bound by default in fish - the reason they work as global shortcuts is because you bound them as global shortcuts.

Comment: The `CTRL + P` is also a global shortcut, in that way. I set it in the app and it works in other applications.